# the error shows Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

when running my code using 'npx react-native run-android' it shows

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUYTL.png)]

I have tried changing my JDK version because it doesn't show anything at the start and after that it has some a little improvement and now it shows this error:

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> 435 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 433 up-to-date
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong: 
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake

> Try: 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 14s

Comment: I suggest that rather than adding an image, post the textual error here. So that it is more readable.

Comment: what version of jdk you installed ?

Comment: I am using jdk 17